# Parsing multiple arrays from JSON to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have this:

```
<?php
    $sql2 = "SELECT dev_id FROM logs";
    if ($br_result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2))
    {
        while ($br_row=mysqli_fetch_row($br_result))
        {
            $uniq_br[] =  $br_row[0];
        }
    }
    $uniq_br = array_unique($uniq_br);
?>


<?php 
    $sql_2 = "SELECT * FROM logs WHERE dev_id = '$value' ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC LIMIT 12";
        $result_br=mysqli_query($conn,$sql_2);
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result_br))
        {
            $json_feed = array($row[2],$row[3],$row[4]);
            echo json_encode($json_feed);
        }
?>
```

And above code returning me ["14","46","2.55"]["11","42","-1.44"]["12","41","-0.86"] etc.
Which I cannot parse in JS to get back "same" array in JS, right?

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: If that's really what the content looks like, you cannot parse that as JSON with the built-in tools. You can write your own parser to interpret it or you can fix the server-side code so that it produces something correct.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm getting above using this:
$json_feed = array($row[2],$row[3],$row[4]);
json_encode($json_feed);

Comment: Looks like you're probably doing that within a loop, and trying to manually construct the final JSON.  Tip: don't

Comment: That is not coming out of `json_encode`.

Comment: I see. I will create "proper" JSON structure using loop in PHP. I do not know how, but thanks for reactions.

Comment: Simply, you generate the entire array you want to pass _first_, then json_encode that one array, once. As Libor points out, it's invalid probably because you're echo'ing json_encode multiple times (and then potentially manually wrapping the `{}`?).

Comment: So, you want to put the `json_encode` line after the loop, change the `$json_feed =` line to `$json_feed[] =`, and add `$json_feed = [];` before the loop.

Comment: Oh, I see Jon. Stupid logical mistake. In JSON I have only one "row" saved. I'm echo'ing each row in loop... :-D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
JSON.parse('[["14", "46", "2.55"], 
            ["11", "42", "-1.44"], 
            ["12", "41", "-0.86"]]');
```

note that your structure is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at this situation:

We have this PHP code:

```
<?php
$row = [
    2=> ["14","46","2.55"],
    3 => ["11","42","-1.44"],
    4 => ["12","41","-0.86"],
];

$json_feed = array($row[2],$row[3],$row[4]); 

print_r(json_encode($json_feed));
```

Result of `print_r` is:

```
[["14","46","2.55"],["11","42","-1.44"],["12","41","-0.86"]]
```

You can just use in JS:

```
JSON.parse('[["14","46","2.55"],["11","42","-1.44"],["12","41","-0.86"]]')
```

Result will be an array like this:

[image: result]